# After losing the focus on the JPanel screen in swing, screen don't show the content

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I am using JTabbedPane with JPanel to display JTable on one tab and text, dropdown and jbutton on other tab.

First time it is working fine but if i minimize or switch screen to other application and come back to my application it display data correct but with a serious problem with tab change in JTabbedPane. Now tab screen goes to blue and don't display the data.(I hope data is there but it is not repainting or refreshing complete window).

Now with blue screen i do the same procedure and change tab in JTabbedPane it shows correct data.

I used repaint but it doesn't work.

Help needed to refresh window or tab correctly.

Comment: Please share [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that illustrates the issue.

Comment: As Max said, the SSCCE is required. Having said that, maybe try revalidate()?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you're doing all modification of Swing components (including altering data in de models or switching tabs manually) via de Event Dispatch Thread. Swing allows the developer to ignore thread safety, but this creates undefined behaviour.

Here's an example for modifying the content of a JComboBox's model.

```
final DefaultComboBoxModel model = (DefaultComboBoxModel) comboBox.getModel();
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        // Add all Swing component modification code here..
        // The line of code below is but an example of what you could do
        model.addElement("String element");
    }
});
```